# How to pass star char in expect spawn?

Tags: bash, escaping, tcl, expect

I wanna run like `ls *` so I tried

```
expect -c 'spawn ls *;expect eof;'
expect -c 'spawn ls {*};expect eof;'
```

but none is working.

My question is how to pass * char in spawn?

Thx!

Comment: Both your commands are exactly equivalent to `ls '*'` in shell: they pass the `*` to `ls`, instead of treating it as an instruction to put filenames on the command line instead. So what you really want is **not** to pass the asterisk to `ls`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`spawn` does not, on its own, invoke a shell, but directly invokes the command you're telling it to run. Thus, the operations that would normally be performed by a shell (like replacing a glob expression, such as `*`, with a list of filenames) don't take place.

The following has `ls *` be run *by a shell*, such that the shell can perform the glob expansion you intend:

```
expect -c 'spawn sh -c {ls *}; expect eof;'
```